# setError alongwith onClick for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Normal error displayed using `setError()` method:

[image: Screenshot #1]

Problem:

[image: Screenshot #2]

Okay so I have another `EditText` in same dialog having an `OnClickListener` for showing the `DatePicker` dialog. When I `setError()` it shows the red alert icon and when I click on that icon, the event is still handled by `OnClick` on `EditText` and `DatePicker` pops up, hence I cannot view the error message.

What I want : If I click on the icon, it must show the error message, and if I click outside the icon it should show the `DatePicker`.

Comment: use custom layout and do handle the same

Answer (score 2):

Oh man, I literally had this problem 2 days ago. I found no way to make it both HAVE focus (in order to display the message, AND also create a pop-up of the date picker. What I ended up doing is wrapping `EditText` into a `TextInputLayout` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/birthDateInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_birth_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/birth_date_hint"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And then instead of setting the error on the edit text, I set the error on the `TextInputLayout` instead like this:

```
birthDateInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
birthDateInputLayout.setError("This field cannot be empty.");
```

> NOTE: It **does not** look exactly the same as the regular way of setting error on `EditText`, but it does look nice enough and solves the problem a bit differently.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll consider changing UI if nothing else works. For now, looking for a solution without changes to the UI as far as possible.

Comment: @Xc0d3r I think that you should proceed with this solution even if it means to change your code. This way you'll have a clean code that works well, compared to any possible hacks that you'll have to write in order to make the other solution work. And on more personal opinion, I really hate that mode to display an error, it looks really bad and doesn't blend with the Material Design.

Comment: I agree @IulianPopescu, my neighbor :) This really somehow blends into Material much better. But if the OP still wants to chase his original idea, that's fine too. My solution may still help someone after all.

Comment: @Xc0d3r This will not affect the look of the UI at all when there's no error, only when there is. You can try and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to check whether error is null inside onclickListener.
ie,

```
if(((EditText)view).getError() == null) {
//Handle your click for showing picker
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this following code according to your code
when complete all field and second date edit text set error to null.any query you can ask

```
mEditText.setError(null);//removes error
mEditText.clearFocus();    //clear focus from edit text
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem he has? He doesnt just wanna remove the error. Read the question please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
onClick(View v){
    if(editText.getError() != null ){
       editText.requestFocus(); // to show error message
    }else{
        // open date picker dialog here or do you stuff here 
    }
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! this works but only when the `EditText` is **focusable**. Unfortunately in my case, I don't want the user to type in date manually. One solution I thought of was using `TextView` instead of `EditText`.

Comment: you can restrict user to type in edittext in your case as well just to show the error message only.

Comment: after requesting focus use this editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);